# Python, how to print specific items from lists in lists?

Tags: python, list, printing

I am trying to print the first and last item of all the lists inside my list of lists `num_list`.

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

for x in range(0,3):
    for y in range(0,1) and range(2,3):
        print(num_list[x][y])
```

But this is just printing `3,30,300` and skipping the `1,10` and `100`.

What is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: `range(0,1) and range(2,3)` this doesn't do what you think it does. It just returns `range(2,3)` because `bool(range(0,1))` is `True` (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and)). What you want is `for y in [0, 2]` (I expect).

Comment: Thank you @FHTMitchell, why does range(0,1) return true?

Comment: @FHTMitchell Just thinking about it more, if range(0,1) returns True, then why does range(2,3) return range(2,3) and not True also?

Comment: `range(0,1)` doesn't return `True`, `bool(range(0,1))` returns `True`, as does `bool(range(2,3))` because `bool(sequence)` is (normally) the same as `len(sequence) > 0`. `a and b` is the same as `b if a else a`. This is a pretty fundamental python concept. See the link I provided earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @FHTMitchell. When you say bool(sequence) is normally the same as len(sequence), does that mean that as the string "range(0,1)" has a length > 0, it returns true? Sorry if I'm way off on this! Just trying to understand.

Comment: It's nothing to do with strings. I'm talking about the value `range(0, 1)`. Try `print(len(range(0, 1)))` in your python console. It's `1` because `range(0, 1)` represents the sequence `[0]`. You can extract a visualisation of any `range` object by passing it's values into a list, such as `list(range(20))`. You can have empty ranges, such as `range(0,0)` and these are considered `False`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell - thanks again, when you say 'It's 1 because range(0, 1) represents the sequence [0]' could you expand on that a little further as I'm getting lost. Is 'the sequence [0]' an empty list (I'm thinking that because of the square brackets) or is a sequence a type of thing within python that I have yet to come across (e.g. a type of variable)?

Comment: A sequence is an abstraction of "ordered data" and it is actually defined as an *abstract class* in the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) module as `Sequence`. `list`, `tuple` and `range` are all sub-classes of it. When I say sequence, I'm doing so because *technically* a `range` isn't a `list`, but we can pretend it is (and make it into one by passing to `list`). `[0]` is not an empty sequence, it's a sequence with one element `0`. `[]` is an empty sequence.

Comment: I'm using square brackets because all sequences can be *represented* as lists, even if they *technically* aren't. For example `(1,2,3)`, `[1,2,3]` and `range(1,4)` all represent the same **sequence** even though they have different **types**. There are collections which aren't sequences such as the set `{1,2,3}` since sets have no order. `{1,2,3} == {2,3,1} == {3,1,2}`

Comment: Great answer @FHTMitchell, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing.

**Ex:**

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

for i in num_list:
    print(i[0], i[-1])   #i[-1] == negative indexing.
```

**Output:**

```
1 3
10 30
100 300
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind explaining why you are using -1? I understand that i[0] is 1,10,100... but why is i[-1] 3,30,300?

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh, to 'activate' negative list index do you simply have to use a negative symbol? Then the code knows you are using NLI?

Comment: @JoshuaESummers Not exactly. It's not the symbol, it's the value. `(-1)` is the value. You could just as well do `x = -1` and then `i[x]`.

Comment: negative 1 index accesses the very last element.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use range to achieve your task.
Anyway, even if you would like to, there is a mistake in your code in the line

```
range(0,1) and range(2,3)
```

By definition `and` returns the first value which is False, otherwise if there is not, it returns the last value in the expression.
Thus, in your case it only returns `range(2,3)`.

Indeed,

```
range(0,1) and range(2,3)
```

returns

```
range(2, 3)
```

since `bool(range(0,1))` and `bool(range(2,3))` are both evaluated as True.
This is why they are both non-empty sequences. Indeed `bool(range(2,2))` would be evaluated as `False` being empty. For more details see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

You should rather write something like

```
import itertools

num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

for x in range(0,3):
    for y in itertools.chain(range(0,1), range(2,3)):
        print(num_list[x][y])
```

using [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Comment: Thank you. What does intertools do?

Comment: When you say 'and returns the first value which is False, otherwise if there is not, it returns the last value in the expression' - do you mean that range(0,1) is false? or are you saying because range(0,1) is not false it returns the last value (range(2,3))? Sorry I'm a bit confused!

Comment: itertools (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) includes a set of function to handle iterators. In your case, you want to iterate over two iterators `range(0,1)` and `range(2,3)`. To do that, you can use `itertools.chain` like in the example. In your specific case it's not necessary as a direct indexing of the list is enough.

Comment: since `bool(range(0,1))`  and `bool(range(2,3))` are evaluated as True, the returned one is `bool(range(2,3))`. This is why you are getting only `3, 30, 300` as output.

Comment: Just thinking about it more, if range(0,1) returns True, then why does range(2,3) return range(2,3) and not just 'True' also?

Answer (score 1):

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

for x in range(0,3):

    for y in range(len(num_list[x])):
        if y==0 or y==2:
            print(num_list[x][y])
```

you can use above code

Answer (score 1):

Probably the smallest solution:

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]
for x in num_list:
    print(x[0], x[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

range(0,1) and range(2,3) returns => range(2,3)

Comment: This answer is a declarative statement. Which is fine enough (not really). Can you elaborate on why python does this and *attempt* to address *"What is a good way to solve this problem?"* Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_list = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]]

for each in num_list:
    print (each[0], each[-1])
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a little bit please? What does each do? And what does the each[0], each[-1] structure mean? As in is it printing between 'each[0]' and 'each[-1]' which is some how equivalent to range (0,1)?

Comment: `each` is just every element of `num_list` so on the first iteration `each` is `[1,2,3]`, on the second it's `[10,20,30]` and on the third `[100,200,300]`. `each[0], each[-1]` is the first and last element of every `each` so e.g. `[1,3]`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell This code is written in python3

@JoshuaESummers `each` represent the elements in the list num_list.
That means `each` will have value `[1, 2, 3]` in first iteration, `[10, 20, 30]` in second iteration and then finally it will be `[100, 200, 300]`.



First iteration : print each[0], each[-1] output => 1 3

First iteration : print each[0], each[-1] output => 10 30

First iteration : print each[0], each[-1] output => 100 300

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer  based on the original solution but it is not the best one

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

for x in range(0, len(num_list)):

    for y in range(0,3,2): #where the change should be
        print(num_list[x][y],end=' ') #display the results in one line
```

Comment: What are the pros/cons of your solution?

Comment: this answer is a sort of correction to the author's answer not an innovative one, it would be more efficient to use a negative indexing approach like @Shivam Jha solution

Answer (score 0):

Other solution if you want short oneliners:

3 oneliner solutions if printing in one line is good for you:

```
print(*[num for elem in vec for num in elem[0:3:2]])

print(*[num for elem in vec for num in elem[0:1]+elem[2:3]])

print(*[num for elem in vec for num in elem[0:1]+elem[-1:]])
```

Output:

```
1 3 10 30 100 300
```

or to print one number per line:

```
print('\n'.join([str(num) for elem in vec for num in elem[0:3:2]]))

1
3
10
30
100
300
```